# What are the steps I need to take before removing an old Windows folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, permissions, multi-boot

I had Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 10 set up as a dual boot on my machine. I have been doing some research, but when it comes to removing a second OS from my computer I am super green and cautious to make any changes.

I have done the following successfully:

1. Opened MSCONFIG
2. Deleted Windows 7 Ultimate from boot (pointed to D:\Windows)
3. Restarted
4. Opened Explorer
5. Right clicked "This PC"
6. Selected "Properties"
7. Selected "Advanced system settings"
8. Selected "Settings..." under "Start-up and Recovery" found on the "Advanced tab"
9. Unchecked "Time to display list of operating systems" and validated that I only have 1 OS in the drop down for "Default operating system"
10. Restarted successfully

I think I am ready to clean up the old D:\Windows and D:\Program Files folders, but **TrustedInstaller** has ownership of those directories and I'm hesitant to take ownership and wipe them clean, simply because I don't know if by default there are other prerequisites I need to go through before I can clean out my old Windows 7 install.

Any help would be appreciated! Taking ownership and wiping those directories is too dangerous to go in blindly.

Comment: Is there any reason you don’t want to just reformat D:?

Comment: Yeah, I have my entire music collection on the D drive

Comment: Removing windows 7 was really just so that I could make more free space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could backup or sync your music collection onto a Cloud storage or another drive. Them format or delete your Windows 7 partition.

If you really need to keep Windows 7 partition but need to free space, enter WinRE and take ownership of those folders you want to delete, run command line to clean them.

You may be interested in this article: [How to Properly Delete a OS in a Dual Boot](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/210983-dual-boot-delete-os.html).